# RealmSwiftで１対多のリレーションの「多」の一覧を取得したい

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, realm

realmでデータベースの操作を練習している初心者です。
[タグ機能の実装、データベースの設計について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/14487/)
こちらの回答の方法でデータベースを動かすことができました。

そこで、タグの一覧をTableViewなどで表示して操作したいのですが、ノートに付いているタグの一覧の取得の仕方がわかりません。

ノートに付けたタグの一覧の取得の仕方を教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

**環境**

- Xcode 9.2
- Swift 4
- realm-swift-3.1.1

Answer (score 1):

listから普通に取得できました。
失礼しました。